# Can the commutative and associative properties be used together

Tags: abstract-algebra

The commutative property says we can swap the order of the number and still get  the same result $a + b = b + a$.

The associative property  says it doesn't matter how we group the numbers (i.e. which we calculate first) $$(a + b) + c  =  a + (b + c),$$ 
so if I changed the order of the numbers and how I grouped them 
$$(a + b) + c  = c + (b + a).$$

Is this equation considered to be using the associative and the commutative property?
Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: That is just the commutative property twice.  $(a+b)+c=(b+a)+c=c+(b+a)$.

Comment: If you want to combine the two rules, try something like $(a+b)+c=a+(b+c)=(b+c)+a$.

Comment: You can also do it this way (which works also for much more complicated examples) : First , omit all parantheses, then change the order of the summands as you want, and then you can put parantheses wherever you want. All this does not effect the sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Associativity says

$$(a+b)+c=a+(b+c)=a+b+c$$ (dropping the parenthesis is possible) while commutativity allows you to write

$$(a+b)+c=(b+a)+c=c+(a+b)=c+(b+a).$$

As you see, the two properties don't coincide.

With both,

$$a+b+c=a+c+b=b+a+c=b+c+a=c+a+b=c+b+a.$$